# Nodejs Express and MySQL connection randomly closed

Tags: mysql, node.js, express

I have a front-end app on app.example.com

_______backend app on api.example.com

My API connects to the backend this way:

```js
const mysql = require("mysql2");
const dbConfig = require("../config/db.config.js");

// Create a connection to the database
const connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host: dbConfig.HOST,
  port: dbConfig.PORT,
  user: dbConfig.USER,
  password: dbConfig.PASSWORD,
  database: dbConfig.DB
});

// open the MySQL connection
connection.connect(error => {
  if (error) throw error;
  console.log("Successfully connected to the database.");
});

module.exports = connection;
```

One day, I'm logging on to app.example.com, everything works fine.
An other day, I'm logging again on the app, I made some request, and here's the response :

```
mg {headers: rg, status: 500, statusText: "OK", url: "https://api.example.com/endpoint", ok: false, …}
error: {message: "Can't add new command when connection is in closed state"}
headers: rg {normalizedNames: Map(0), lazyUpdate: null, lazyInit: ƒ}
message: "Http failure response for https://api.example.com/entries: 500 OK"
name: "HttpErrorResponse"
ok: false
status: 500
statusText: "OK"
url: "https://api.example.com/endpoint"
```

What's the problem ? Do i have to use createPool instead of createConnection ? Because until now, I have to restart the backend each time it doesn't work... Here's the error I have in my logs :

```
error:  { Error: Can't add new command when connection is in closed state
    at Connection._addCommandClosedState (/home/example/domains/api.example.com/public_html/node_modules/mysql2/lib/connection.js:137:17)
    at Connection.query (/home/example/domains/api.example.com/public_html/node_modules/mysql2/lib/connection.js:510:17)
    at Function.Entry.create (/home/example/domains/api.example.com/public_html/models/entry.model.js:22:9)
    at exports.create (/home/example/domains/api.example.com/public_html/controllers/entry.controller.js:29:11)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/example/domains/api.example.com/public_html/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at next (/home/example/domains/api.example.com/public_html/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:137:13)
    at Route.dispatch (/home/example/domains/api.example.com/public_html/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:112:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/example/domains/api.example.com/public_html/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at /home/example/domains/api.example.com/public_html/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:281:22
    at Function.process_params (/home/example/domains/api.example.com/public_html/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12) fatal: true }
```

Comment: Does your backend throw an error? What does its log say? Are you creating a connection an constantly using it? Is there large idle periods on this connection? Is the [wait_timeout](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_wait_timeout) exceeded.

Comment: You could catch that error and then re-instigate the connection and try again.

Comment: Hi @danblack, thanks fot your answer. I add the logs of my backend server, which is pretty the same than what my front gave me. I suppose that ou're right, it's because there is a wait_timeout exceeded. Is it possible to set this variable to unlimited?

Comment: while its possible to set a high value here, if there's a way the code can connect the error and reconnect it would be a bit more durable is a wide range of scenarios, like a database restart.

Comment: And what about using a poolConnection instead o creating only one?

Comment: I'm not familiar enough with nodejs to make a recommendation like that. It might be right, but I'll let someone else answer that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so I create a pool and I didn't have the problem anymore. Fixed.